# how to add in Visual Studio 2010 WinForm Object to a C++ Console Application Project

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, winapi, console-application

I am building a C++ Console Application which makes some OpenGL printing.
The entire thing is done by glut and gl libraries. My new goal is to add some Windows Forms to the project so one could "configure" the 'game' with some textbox and other controls provided by VS before the console appliction starts.
I know that the best solution for the current problem is to add Win32 API, but I don't know how to integrate console application project with win32 API alltogether.
I know that in C# it's done quite easily with the `.ShowDialog()` command.

Comment: Please note that it is always a good idea to include an actual question (with a question mark) in your, ehm, question.

Comment: MikeNakis:Im sorry i wasn't clear enough. im trying to understand how to initialize a new Win32(Windows Form) Window in a C++ console Application code.

Comment: You need to get the CLR loaded and initialized.  There are some shortcuts to this but that won't do, you'll have fairly rich interop when you use dialogs.  It is a wholeheckofalot easier to have a C++/CLI Winforms project create a console window and call native code than the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although launching a window from a console application is perfectly doable, that window will not be responsive, because your console application does not have a message queue. (Or rather, it has a message queue, but it is implemented by code that you have no control over.) So, you can open up a window, draw in it, and force it to manually update, but you cannot receive user input in it.

I would suggest that you forget about doing it this way, and you write a little windowed application instead, which prompts for the configuration and then launches the console application passing it the configuration as command-line parameters, or fills-in a configuration file for the console application to read.

Comment: MikeNakis: Thanks for the answer. well i like the first part, in that case i can simply create .NET window which executes the console Appliction. my problem is when the console Application shuts down. i want to open another window. maybe i can execute from the C++ part another .Net window? i dont know if this solution is "correct"

Comment: Of course you can launch your windows application from your console application if you wish. What you can also do is to keep your windows application running and just hide the window for as long as the console application runs, and re-show it once it terminates. This way you do not closely couple them: the windows application knows about the console application, but the console application does not know anything about the windows application.